# Explaining the motivation behind two different definitions of a generic point

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, terminology

This question is primarily regarding the definition of a generic point of a topological space that I came across in Qing Liu's *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves*. First I will give the definition of a generic point that I am used to:

***Definition I am used to:*** Let $X$ be a topological space. A point $x\in X$ is a **generic point** of $X$ if $x$ is dense in $X$. (In particular this implies that if a topological space has a generic point, then the space must be irreducible. So, reducible spaces do not have generic points.)

***Definition in Qing Liu's book***: Let $X$ be a topological space. Given $x,y \in X$, we say $x$ **specializes** to $y$ iff $y \in \overline{\{x\}}$. We say $x$ is a **generic point** of $X$ if $x$ is the unique point of $X$ that specializes to $x$.

From what I have been able to deduce so far, under Liu's definition of a generic point, reducible spaces can have generic points. For example if we take a ring $A$, then the generic points of $Spec(A)$ (according to Liu's definition) are all the minimal primes of $A$. And certainly, $Spec(A)$ is reducible unless $Nil(A)$ is a prime ideal.

Also, Liu's definition implies that if $O \subset X$ is a non-empty open subset and $x \in O$ is a generic point of $O$, then $x$ is a generic point of $X$. So, something that is locally a generic point is also globally a generic point. This is not true for the first definition.

So far I had been happily using the first definition of a generic point, but Qing Liu's definition has thrown me a little off-guard. I guess I do not fully understand the motivation behind Qing Liu's definition, and also the need for two different definitions that are clearly not equivalent. Which definition do people generally use?

Looking at Wikipedia it seems that the first definition of a generic point of a topological space is more prevalent. Any explanation or motivation for Qing Liu's definition will be useful, along with an explanation (perhaps?) of why there are two different definitions for the same concept.

*Also, if answers are too long to type up, then references that explain the concept of generic point are more than welcome. But, I hope they address the questions I have asked.*

Comment: Why would one minimal prime be in the closure of another?

Comment: @Ryan: What do you mean why would one minimal prime be in the closure of another?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a purely topological point of view (since I know virtually nothing of algebraic geometry), Qing Liu's definition is a natural generalization of the other one.

Let $X$ be a topological space. Write $x\preceq y$ iff $\operatorname{cl}\{x\}\subseteq\operatorname{cl}\{y\}$; clearly $\preceq$ is a preorder (or quasiorder) on $X$; if $X$ is $T_0$, which I believe is generally the case in your setting, $\preceq$ is a partial order. Qing Liu’s definition makes a point generic iff it is maximal in $\langle X,\preceq\rangle$: $x$ is generic iff $x\preceq y$ iff $x=y$. The other definition makes a point generic iff it is a maximum in $\langle X,\preceq\rangle$: for all $y\in X$, $y\preceq x$. Let me call these notions *QL-generic* and *strongly generic* for short.

Let $M=\{x\in X:x\text{ is }\preceq\text{-maximal}\}$; then $\big\{\operatorname{cl}\{x\}:x\in M\big\}$ is a partition of $X$ into closed, irreducible subsets. Thus, a QL-generic point $x\in X$ is strongly generic in $\operatorname{cl}\{x\}$, which is an irreducible component of $X$. My guess is that some people find that this extra generality makes some things easier to talk about.

**Added 22 May 2023:** In fact this is seriously incorrect as it stands: $\big\{\operatorname{cl}\{x\}:x\in M\big\}$ need not be a partition of $X$. Indeed, it does not necessarily even cover $X$ without some restriction on $X$. For instance, let $$\tau=\{\varnothing,\Bbb Z\}\cup\{(\leftarrow,n]:n\in\Bbb Z\}\,;$$ then $\tau$ is a $T_0$ topology on $\Bbb Z$, and $\operatorname{cl}\{n\}=[n,\to)$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z$, so no $n\in\Bbb Z$ is $\preceq$-maximal.

Let $X$ be a [*sober space*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sober_space), so that every irreducible closed subset has a unique generic point, and let $\mathscr{C}$ be the set of irreducible components of $X$; then for each $C\in\mathscr{C}$ there is a unique $x_C\in C$ such that $C=\operatorname{cl}\{x_C\}$, and clearly $x_C\in M$. It is [true in any space](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/004U) that every point is contained in an irreducible component, so $\big\{\operatorname{cl}\{x\}:x\in M\big\}=\mathscr{C}$ covers $X$. However, $\mathscr{C}$ still need not be a partition, as the members of $\mathscr{C}$ may overlap.

Nevertheless, if $X$ is sober it is true that every QL-generic point $x\in X$ is strongly generic in the irreducible component $\operatorname{cl}\{x\}$ of $X$, which is all that I actually wanted. And having now seen the book in question, I can say that Liu’s definition of *generic point* is made in the context of schemes, which *are* sober spaces.

Comment: This is helpful. Thank you.

Comment: And it is true that schemes are $T_0$. But, I was wondering if there is a standard definition for an arbitrary topological space. Are you aware of such a definition?

Comment: I still find it a little strange that there are two different definitions in the literature.

Comment: @Rankeya: No, I’m not. My impression is that the idea and terminology both come from algebraic geometry, not from general topology.

Comment: M.Scott: Do you think I should remove the general topology tag then?

Comment: For some reason I cannot type you full name with an @ sign before.

Comment: @Rankeya: I don’t think that any harm is done by keeping the tag; I probably wouldn’t have noticed the question without it.

Comment: Why does $\{\operatorname{cl}\{x\}:x\in M\}$ partition $X$? In Proposition $4.12$ in Liu's book it is shown that there is a correspondence between the irreducible components of a scheme $X$ and its QL-generic points - but irreducible components need to be disjoint (see Example $4.8$ in Liu). So we can show at best that $\{\operatorname{cl}\{x\}:x\in M\}$ covers $X$ (in the case of, say, a $T_0$-space $X$), i.e., for each $x\in X$, there exists a GL-generic $y$ such that $x\in\{y\}$. Is that true, and if so, why?

Comment: @ShaVuklia: There is indeed a serious problem there. Eleven years later I have no idea what I was thinking, but I’ve added a note explaining what is wrong with the original answer and how (in the context in which Liu’s definition was made) the argument can be repaired to enable the same guess. (Whether the guess is correct is another matter, and I know far too little about algebraic geometry judge.)

Answer (score 0):

I'll point out why you don't have to be worried about any of the things you listed. First thing, I see no reason why irreducible closed subsets can't have generic points according to Liu's definition. The definition is made for an arbitrary X, so consider $Y\subset X$ closed and irreducible as a new topological space with the subspace topology to get the generic point there.

I'm also not sure what the concern about reducible spaces is about. If you break $Spec(R)$ up into its irreducible components, then as you point out the minimal primes are the generic points of the these components (which are irreducible). There is still no generic point for the whole space $Spec(R)$ which is still consistent with the first definition, and moreover most people probably implicitly extend the definition of generic point in the first sense to work on irreducible components.

For the concern about "locally" being a generic point implies being a global generic point. Again, since you made the comment about irreducible already, this shouldn't be a problem for the first definition. If $X$ is irreducible, then any open set is dense, and hence if $x$ is a generic point of some open $O$, then even in the first definition it is a generic point of $X$.

Edit: Removed the first sentence, because people were apparently not reading what I wrote and just commenting on the first sentence. The point I'm making is if you generalize the first definition in the obvious way to reducible spaces by working on irreducible components (note that I did say this in the post) or if you restrict the second definition to the case where you have a generic point in the first sense, then they become equivalent. So in that sense, there is no "fundamental difference" that seemed to be alluded to in the question.

Comment: Wait, do you agree that by the first definition only an irreducible space can have a generic point, and by the second definition, reducible spaces can also have generic points?

Comment: They are plainly **not** equivalent. Qing Liu’s definition is more general.

Comment: I don't really see after this basic observation how these two definitions can be equivalent. For instance, under the first definition $Spec(A)$ for a ring $A$ has a generic point only if it is irreducible. However, by the second definition, for any non-zero ring $A$, $Spec(A)$ has generic points.

Comment: @Matt: Please look at Qing Liu's definition again. Your second paragraph is incorrect. A generic point of an irreducible component of an affine, is by Qing Liu's definition a generic point of the space, because this point corresponds to a minimal prime, which only specializes to itself.

Comment: Also, I never talked about any fundamental difference. I was plainly just following the consequences of the two definitions, and pointing out that they are not equivalent.

Comment: In your update, by the first definition $\eta$ is not a generic point $X$, because $\overline{\{\eta\}} \neq X$ in general.

Comment: According to your claim, then every point of a topological space $X$ is "a" generic point of the topological space, because the closure of every point is irreducible.

Comment: What is going on here? Is my writing really that unclear? I wrote that $\eta$ is the generic point of $Y$. I'm using "the" to mean definition in the first sense and "a" to mean definition in the second sense. The explanation is showing how these two definitions are related.

Comment: But, even then by the second definition $\eta$ is not a generic point of $X$. Take $Spec(A)$ again. Every prime ideal $p \subset A$ is a generic point of $V(p)$, which is irreducible. But, every prime ideal $p$ is not "a" generic point of $Spec(A)$ by the second definition. Only the minimal primes are generic points of $Spec(A)$ by the second definition.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then I retract my update. What I wrote before was fine and I don't really understand the comments from before.

Comment: Never mind. There are obvious communication barriers this way. I will let your answer be.