# Qing Liu's definition of specialization of point - follow-up question

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, terminology

The definition of a generic point in Qing Liu's book "Algebraic geometry and arithmetic curves" has been discussed before in these questions:
[Explaining the motivation behind two different definitions of a generic point](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/117338/128787),
[A question about generic points.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/406656/a-question-about-generic-points)

My question is slightly different since I can't figure how a simple statement in the next page comes. Let me give some background.

**Liu's definition of generic point:** For a topological space $X$ we say that *$x$ specializes to $y$* if $y\in\overline{\{x\}}$. We say that $x$ is a *generic point* of $X$ if $x$ is the unique point of $X$ that specializes to $x$ (def. 4.10, pg. 63).

**Remarks:**

1. $x$ specializes to $y$ is equivalent to $\overline{\{y\}}\subseteq\overline{\{x\}}$.
2. $x$ being generic is equivalent to the following: There exists *no* $y$ such that $\overline{\{x\}}\subseteq\overline{\{y\}}$.
3. The other definition of a generic point, i.e. that $\overline{\{x\}}=X$, is less general than Liu's definition, as was remarked in the previous questions.

**My question:** In the next page there is prop. 4.12 wherein its proof there is the following statement:

> Let $X$ be a scheme, $Z$ an irreducible component of it and $U$ an affine open of $X$ such that $U\cap Z\neq \emptyset.$ Then $Z\cap U$ is an irreducible component of $U$. Let $\xi$ be the generic point of $Z\cap U$. **Then $Z=\overline{\{\xi\}}.$**

I can't get my head around how it is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

To see this, you can just prove that $\overline{Z \cap U} = Z$ (closure in $X$); indeed $Z = (Z \setminus U) \cup \overline{Z \cap U}$ so by irreducibility we can conclude.

To end, we need to check that $Z = \overline{\overline{\left \{\xi\right \}}^U}^X$. There is an obvious inclusion of LHS into RHS so again by maximality, we can reduce to proving that: if $U \subset X$ open, and $T$ irreducible in $U$, then $\overline{T}$ is irreducible in $X$. Indeed, if $\overline{T} = V_1 \cup V_2$ (with $V_1,V_2$ closed) then you see that there is an obvious inclusion $T \subset \overline{T} \cap U= (V_1 \cap U) \cup (V_2 \cap U)$ and hence $T = V_1 \cap U$ for instance, so $\overline{T} = \overline{V_1 \cap U} \subset \overline{V_1} = V_1$.

Comment: Don't you end up with $cl_X(cl_U(\xi))=Z$? Why's $cl_X(cl_U(\xi))=cl_X(\xi)$?

Comment: @user128787 edited!

Comment: No hold on a second! The equality that you prove in the edit is already established! Specifically, you say "we need to check that $Z=\overline{\overline{\{\xi\}}^U}^X$" and then you prove it but this already holds from $\overline{Z\cap U}^X=Z$. The question I'm asking is why $\overline{\overline{\xi}^U}^X$ equals $\overline{\xi}^X$?